# A basic minimization problem

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Does the following function has a global minimum
$$f(x) = \frac{2x +1}{1-e^{-(1-\alpha) x}}$$

where $x$ is a positive real number.

for $0< \alpha < 1$

Comment: Note that (for the purposes of this question) this can be just as easily written $f(x) = \frac{2x+1}{1-e^{-\alpha x}}$.

Comment: Are you interested in a global minimum for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, or for some more restricted set?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Brian Tung in a comment, let us replace $1-\alpha$ by $\beta$. So, the function write $$f(x)=\frac{2 x+1}{1-e^{-\beta x}}$$ Computing its derivative with respect to $x$ and simplifying $$f'(x)=\frac{e^{\beta  x} \left(\beta  (-(2 x+1))+2 e^{\beta  x}-2\right)}{\left(e^{\beta 
   x}-1\right)^2}$$ which cancels if $$\beta  (2 x+1)-2 e^{\beta  x}+2=0$$ Any equation which can write of rewrite $A+B x+C \log(D+Ex)=0$ has solution in terms of Lambert function. For this case, we should get a zero for  $$x_*=-\frac{2+\beta +2 W\left(-e^{-\frac{\beta }{2}-1}\right)}{2 \beta }$$ which is defined for all $\beta$'s in the considered range.

The second derivative test (not the most simple) shows that $f''(x_*)$ is always positive so $x_*$ corresponds to a global minimum.

After some rather tedious manipulations $$f(x_*)=-\frac{2 W\left(-e^{-\frac{\beta }{2}-1}\right)}{\beta }$$